# document.execCommand('removeFormat') failing on Chrome when trying to remove format set by document.execCommand('hiliteColor')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, execcommand, brave

I'm adding a background to some selected text in a contenteditable element via `document.execCommand('hiliteColor', false, '#d4ecff');`.

If the selected text contains some formatting tags (`<b></b>` for instance), calling `document.execCommand('removeFormat')` on the selection does not remove all the formats. It's like the background colour is passed to the text formerly encompassed into `<b></b>`.

I'm facing the issue on Chrome (version 100.0.4896.75 - 64 bits) as well as Brave (version 1.37.111 Chromium: 100.0.4896.79  - 64 bits). Everything seems to work as expected on Firefox.

Here's a demo and steps to reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/L82ogcf5/

*PS: I know that the use of `document.execCommand()` is no longer recommendended, so please do not point that out. It's irrelevant until the feature is really deprecated (we all know that is not going to happen anytime soon).*

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a hiliteColor! But then you want to Remove *any* format.
First the `<b>` tag will be removed, and only after a second click the `hiliteColor` will be removed.

What you want instead is:

```js
// Remove hiliteColor, not other text formatting
btn2.onclick = () => document.execCommand("hiliteColor", false, "transparent");
```

Example:

```js
const btn1 = document.querySelector("#btn1");
btn1.onclick = () => document.execCommand("hiliteColor", false, "red");

const btn2 = document.querySelector("#btn2");
btn1.onclick = () => document.execCommand("hiliteColor", false, "transparent");
```

```css
#input {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
Steps to reproduce:
<ol>
  <li>Select all the text inside #input</li>
  <li>Click on the button 1 - "add background colour"</li>
  <li>Click on the button 2 - "remove format</li>
  <li>Do you see a red background where the bold text was? Here's my bug</li>
</ol>
<button id="btn1">add background colour</button>
<button id="btn2">remove format</button>
<div id="input" contenteditable="true">
  I am a real
  <strong>nice test</strong> string
</div>
```

PS: this technology is sadly about to go dead (OK, maybe not so soon because the so many applications that at this date are driven on `contenteditable` and the execCommand). Just because, introduced by IE, and with the rise of competitor browsers they all disagreed on the specs and it slowly became an unhandleable beast... with no replacement currently in active development or written specs, AFAIK.

Comment: `document.execCommand("hiliteColor", false, "transparent")` may totally removes the styled span on Chrome, but in Firefox a  `<span style="background-color: transparent;"></span>` will remain and I'd like to avoid saving that into my database.

Comment: @LoBellin I Understand... What about iterating the selection Elements recursively and removing all the applied styles? (FYI: but doing that you'll also remove the previously added `<b>` tag from the selection!)

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if the simplest (and unfortunately the ugliest) wouldn't be to call document.execCommand("removeFormat") twice.

Comment: @LoBellin You cannot be guaranteed if it's needed to be called twice or *N* times, depending in how many nested stales you have.

Answer (score -1):

first of all, .execCommand is decapitated, second, in chromium, the removeFormat function works in layers. It removed the background color because it was the first layer of formatting. It only removed the bold on the bold text because it was the first layer of formatting there. Try repeating the command 4 times for highlight, bold, italics, and underline. I presume that you are trying to create a text box with adjustable formatting?

Just for this example, a solution would be instead of `clearformatting`, do `undo` as your command.

Or, you could do execCommand again, set the highlight color to white or transparent or something.